# Access to an undefined property trait larastan

Tags: laravel, phpdoc, phpstan

I´m trying to solve errors in my proyect with larastan. One error that this library, returned it´s: `Access to an undefined property App\Cargador\Prevalidaciones\PrevalidarCodificacionUTF8::$tarea`

```
PrevalidarCodificacionUTF8
```

this class use personaliced trait, and in this class i´m adding, `php-doc` to try solve this message, but always return this message:

```
Access to an undefined property App\Cargador\Prevalidaciones\PrevalidarCodificacionUTF8::$tarea.
```

I´m adding to Trait class:

```
/**
 *  @param integer $tarea
 */
```

and i add this `php-doc` to my class, that call my trait. But i can´t solve this message.

I don´t know that code i can add to this question.

Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english

Comment: you need to provide more code. How we can be sure is $tarea really exists?

Comment: @AliÖzen  Sorry for my bad code, i think that i solve my problem. I add `protected $tarea` in my trait and phpstan not return this message